# Are sockets the only way an application can communicate over the internet?

Tags: sockets, networking

I have the impression that sockets are just one of several ways that an application can communicate over the internet, maybe because of the wording in some tutorials I have read recently where it seems like sockets have been chosen as the most efficient tool out of many for the job.

Is this assumption right or do all networking applications use sockets on some level?

Edit: To clarify I'm looking for a practical answer. If I want to write some client/server program that will run on two of my computers running either Linux or Windows, should I always think sockets first (or higher level protocol that uses sockets), or are there other equivalents that may be better suited for the job than sockets.

Comment: Sockets are an API construct. If you want to spew raw packets to the NIC's API then you're free to do so.

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you need a practical answer, or an exhaustive one? Some weird OSes don't have sockets but provide some other API for TCP/IP? What computer and operating systems do you have in mind?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Please see my edited question

Comment: But you don't tell the most important: what concrete operating system do you want your code to run on?

Comment: Also, what kind of computers do you own? A Linux desktop, or a supercomputer, is not the same as an Arduino

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: I run Ubuntu on one machine, Windows 10 on another, I have Raspberry Pies and an Arduino with an ethernet shield, so if there are important specifics to those combinations I would be interested in knowing about it!

Comment: It is more operating system (or library) specific than hardware specific. You need to dive into documentation (I don't know how Arduino uses Ethernet). Some computers don't have a familiar OS.

Comment: Microsoft Windows has always had non-socket networking APIs, even to this day with e.g. .Net TCPListener and TCPClient classes.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: Is .Net `TCPListener` usable from a C program? Berkeley sockets are for C mostly (and for many implementations above C).

Comment: Socket APIs that are reasonably faithful to "Berkeley" sockets are available in most high-level languages including Java and python. I suspect that most if not all of those eventually end up using native code calls to the system socket library. And C++ code on Windows can make use of .Net classes.

Comment: "*do all networking applications use sockets on some level?*" - **Internet** apps do, yes, since sockets are primarily how apps gain access to IP protocols like TCP and UDP.  **Networking** apps, maybe, depending on the OS and networking protocol used.  Protocols other than TCP/UDP can be used on a local network (IPX, NetBIOS, SMB, etc), and they are not all accessed using socket APIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific. Some (old, or academic) OSes provide weird APIs for [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite), and some OSes don't even do any networking.  IIRC, [Gnu Hurd](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/index.html) has something else than sockets (and probably [Fuschia](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com) also has something else).

In practice, **[Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) are** nearly **a *de facto* standard** (this was not always the case, e.g. [TLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Interface)), at least on Unix-like and POSIX systems (and probably on Windows also) and when programming in C (or related stuff, notably C++).

And you could use higher-level libraries, e.g. [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), [0mq](http://zeromq.org/), or protocol specific libraries (for HTTP, [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) on client side, [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion) on server side, ....) etc ..... They are generally built above sockets.

> do all networking applications use sockets on some level?

On some supercomputers, you can also have [InfiniBand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfiniBand) (and perhaps a variant of MPI using that hardware *without* sockets, but with something else). etc... Sometimes they have some InfinBand specific address family for `socket` ....

<sup>(It is more than ten years that I didn't access any supercomputer, so I could be wrong for the details)</sup>

---

BTW, some consortia like [FIWIRE](https://www.fiware.org/) or [AUTOSAR](https://www.autosar.org/) define their own networking APIs (for niche markets or specific industries).

<sup>(perhaps such consortia are defining an API above sockets; I don't know them well enough; you need to check)</sup>

See also the libraries mentioned near the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47796043/841108).

---

> If I want to write some client/server program that will run on two of my computers running either Linux or Windows, should I always think sockets first (or higher level protocol that uses sockets),

Certainly yes in practice. And I would often consider using some *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) library *above* Berkeley sockets.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and thanks for mentioning the higher level protocols!

Comment: But do all these libraries on some level use sockets, or do they do something else?

Comment: It depends. On some supercomputers, an MPI library is given which uses the InfiniBand hardware using a non-socket API. And some academic OSes have a really different view about TCP...