# compile c++ file failed because can not find the definition of `ssize_t`

Tags: c++, header

I have a c++ header file `socket_client.h` together with a c++ source file `socket_client.cc`. In `socket_client.h`, I have code samples like this:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <string>

ssize_t Send(const void *msg, const size_t msg_size/*send msg size*/);
...
```

In `socket_client.cc`, I have code snippet like this:

```
#include "somewhere/socket_client.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
...
```

When I compile this with gcc 4.8, the compiler will say "error" and complains that it can not find the definition of `ssize_t`; However, when I add `#include <sys/types.h>` in `socket_client.h`, it will compile success.
There is someone else compile it successfully without add `#include <sys/types.h>` with gcc 4.4.

I'm totally confused about this. Is it necessary to add that line? What is the collect way to handle this?

ps:I compile with a tool called blade which is based on scons(and so do those with gcc 4.4).

Comment: Well you *do* use `ssize_t` in the `socket_client.h` header file. And you include that header file *before* you include the `<sys/types.h>` file in `socket_client.cc`. Remember that symbols must be declared *before* they are used.

Comment: What system header are you including complaining about the absence of `ssize_t`? Some system headers require that `<sys/types.h>` is included (although I can't find one right now in the manages on MacOS). Things may still compile, e.g., because the declaration came from somewhere else in on  version of the compiler/standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple, have a look at your include order. You include `socket_client.h` before you include `types.h`. This causes your error. Simply change the order and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. But why there is someone compile successfully with the same code using lower version gcc?

Comment: Because some other header did include `<sys/types.h>` or some other system header without you noticing that.

Comment: @user3162587 This might be the case because some other header in 4.4 included <sys/types.h> and that this fact changed in 4.8. Maybe some include order has changed over the versions. There are many different reasons possible.

Comment: Is it always a correct practice to include those system header files before self defined header files? Or should I include necessary system header files in self defined header file?

Comment: @user3162587 I think the overall order is personal, mine is: Corresponding hpp -> Headers from the same component -> Headers from other components -> System headers. 
For a little discusion check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-file-order-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

[GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) is really old (and 4.4 is completely obsolete) since from 2013 and not really supported anymore. You should **upgrade your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler**, at least to [GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/), and if possible to [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) (and in spring 2018, that would be GCC 8).

<sup>(with efforts, you could compile and install GCC 7 from its source code; and you don't always need root access for that)</sup>

You need to define for what C++ standard you want to code. I strongly recommend **coding in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)** at least, and if possible C++14. In a few months (e.g. mid 2018), [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) could be convenient. C++11 is really different of its predecessors (so it is not even worthwhile to code for an older standard, unless you are forced to).

If you code for C++11, you want to use at least [std::size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) (instead of the old C-specific `size_t`) from `<cstddef>` or `<cstdlib>` etc... - and that standard header should be included before (or inside) yours, e.g. `"somewhere/socket_client.h"`; with a recent `g++`, you should compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`  (to get C++11, all warnings, and debug info). Of course, if you want C++14, use `-std=c++14` ....

C++ is a *very difficult* programming language; if you are (like most of us, me included) still learning it, be sure to learn at least C++11 (or C++14) with some [good C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book.

Look also into some good [C++ reference website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) (and even the appropriate C++ standard document).

BTW, you could find many libraries usable from C++ related to networking. Consider perhaps [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (client side) and [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (server side) if you want to develop or use some [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API) with [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), or [Qt](http://qt.io/), or [Boost](http://boost.org/), or [0mq](http://zeromq.org/) for general messaging (and there are many other libraries).

Most versions of GCC (even very old ones) support the `-H` and `-M` [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html). You could use them (at least to understand what system headers get included).